# styling ActionbarSherlock: textColor of the action-items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I was changing the background  of the Actionbar in my App and to make text readable again I have to change the color of the text. I was successful with title/subtitle and the tab-texts, but I am struggling with the text of the action-items - they stay white no matter what I tried . Anyone has a hint on how to do that?
Also the overflow-icon is white which does not look too good on the wooden background - is that an *extremely* good reason to use the stuff below? I am not really sure what's the reason to not do it, but as I do not have a big device-test-park I better want to be sure ;-)

```
<!-- the following can be used to style the overflow menu button
     only do this if you have an *extremely* good reason to!! -->
<!--<style name="MyOverflowButton" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_menu_view</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_button_background</item>
</style>-->
```

Comment: Try starting with `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"` in your Manifest and then changing your styles. The light theme features dark action items. If by items you mean icons and the associated text. Or just look through the light theme to find out how to change them

Comment: thanks @MichałK - that was a helpful - even makes my styles.xml cleaner - was really not seeing this tree in the forest ;-)

Comment: Glad to have helped. Don't know why I put it in comments instead of answers, but yeah... anyway;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try starting with `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"` in your Manifest and then changing your styles. The light theme features dark action items. Or just look through the light theme to find out how to change them.

Comment: @toobsco42 No you're not, and your suggestion there was not to use ABS.

Answer (score 15):

I also struggled with this, but the solution to changing action item text color was:

```
<style name="My.Theme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

The key here was to use this attribute in the general theme, not in the actionbar style.