# Styling action item background ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I've been trying to create my own action item, but it has benn impossible for me.

What I'm tryind to do, is creating a custom action item layout (color background for example), something like "Thumbs" action bar. I only want to change action items only for one of my activities.

[image]

I've been playing with android:icon and android:actionLayout property for action menu items.. but I got nothing.

Actually, I've seen another threads in StackOverflow, but it didn't help me ...

[Building ActionMode with custom layout in ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863080/building-actionmode-with-custom-layout-in-actionbarsherlock)

[styling ActionbarSherlock: textColor of the action-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062012/styling-actionbarsherlock-textcolor-of-the-action-items)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you customize actionbar as seen in this picture?

Comment: it was for an old project, and I couldn't finally try it. If you could try it it would be good! I think the answer below is right, but I haven't tested yet :)

Sorry and good luck!

Comment: That answer will change the background of all action items. I got it working by using  actionLayout for menu item.

Answer (score 12):

To override `ActionBarSherlock` themes you should proceed like this:

Open `values/abs__themes.xml` from `ActionBarSherlock` library project. You see for example:

```
<style name="Theme.Sherlock" parent="Sherlock.__Theme">
    <!-- Action bar styles (from Theme.Holo) -->
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/abs__cab_background_top_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/abs__cab_background_bottom_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/abs__ic_cab_done_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView</item>
    ...
    // Here is what you wanted
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/abs__item_background_holo_dark</item>
    ...
```

When you have found the item you want to customize (`actionBarItemBackground` in your case), you create your own `themes.xml` inside your project, and add in it:

```
<style name="Custom.Theme.Sherlock" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/my__item_background_holo_dark</item>
</style>
```

This overrides the default `Theme.Sherlock`, setting a custom `actionBarItemBackground`.

Now, instead of using `Theme.Sherlock` in your activity you should use `setTheme(R.style.Custom_Theme_Sherlock)`. You may also want to override the other two themes (`Theme.Sherlock.Light` and `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`)

One more tip, here is the drawable selector used by `ActionBarSherlock` for the default action item background (in holo_light), it uses 9-patch png drawables:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_selector_background_transition_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_selector_background_transition_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_focused_holo" />
<item                                                                                          android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

---

For other basic customizing, you can use this [tool](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&backColor=E4E4E4,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100), it generates styles for you.

Comment: +1 @Michel-F. Portzert Is it possible to have a border around the action item too?If yes how could it be done? same steps as you've shown?

Comment: I didn't have really much time to search, so I would suggest creating a special background xml file inside your "drawable/" folder. Either containing a <shape> with <stroke> and <color> attributes if you only need a colored background, or either a <layer-list> if you need the border on top of a background image,
example: <layer-list><item ><bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        </item><item ><shape >
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FF0000"/>
<solid android:color="#00000000"/>
</shape></item></layer-list>