# Sherlock Actionbar change menu background color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I need to change the background of menu items only. When I tried with actionBarItemBackground, it changes the background of application logo [As u can see in the attachment] also. Any help or link will be appreciated.[image]

Comment: You want to change the brackground of your icons or of the whole actionbar?

Comment: Only the background of menu item. Please see the image attached.

Comment: Check this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397407/styling-action-item-background-actionbarsherlock

Comment: @BasimSherif That answer also saying to use actionBarItemBackground.  I have tried this but that didnt work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom layout for your actionbar item like so:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
         <item android:id="@id/item_text"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:actionLayout="@layout/action_text"/>
    </menu>
```

This is styleable as you wish. Another possibility would be adding only the ID (item_text in the example) and set the background like so:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.item_text);
      item.getActionView().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(/* your color */));

      return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

Comment: I am getting a crash when I tried onPrepareOptionsMenu()</br>
 java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.demo.customtabs.TabActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(RDCTabActivity.java:71)
  at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu(Watson.java:44)
  at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:560)
  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.preparePanel(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:466)
  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:265)
  at

Comment: Did you try to actually debug your crash?

Comment: Do your usual view styling. It should work that way. Maybe it's easier to just use a custom layout.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on Android 4.0+. Here's what worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20077381/56285