# Change default actionbar popup menu background color

Tags: android, layout

I try to change the default color of the popup menu by using styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopUp</item>
</style>

<style name="PopUp" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

I have hooked up this theme in app manifest.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

However this does not change the default grey background of the popup. Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: are you sure u used this theme on right activity in manifest?

Comment: I use the theme on the application tag

Comment: You supporting API 14 + ?

Comment: @AtulOHolic only android 4 and up

Comment: did you see [This](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan yes, does not work either for me, when I copy just the relevant parts

Comment: put theme on activity not on application, i remember i had similar problem.

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz just tried, problem remains

Comment: please see [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopUp</item>
</style>
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopUp</item>
</style>
```

now it works. However it seems that using **android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar** you cannot change the style of the popup through xml.

Comment: Background color changed but now can't change font color.