# Custom Background Color for ActionBar settings area

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, settings

I would like to change the color of my settings Tab located on the ActionBar, I have done very extensive research here and in other sources.

My Android version is `4.4.2.`

My manifest is declared this way:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Basically I am doing what other sources showed me to:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:panelFullBackground">@drawable/menu_background</item>
</style>
```

I also have replaced the `android:panelFullBackground` property for `android:panelBackground`, `android:panelColorBackground` and `android:panelColorForeground` switching from drawable resources to color values for each without results.

Finally I have also tried using ListPopupWindow parent variant:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">     
    <item name="android:panelFullBackground">@drawable/menu_background</item>
</style>
```

Here I have also switched the `android:panelFullBackground` property for `android:panelColorBackground`  and `android:popupBackground` properties mixing them up with `@android:color` and `@drawable` resources too but is not working either.

Can you please tell me an effective way to configure this through the styles.xml file?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the right setting for my styles to accomplish the action bar settings custom color. This post helped as well: [How to change the background color of Action Bar's Option Menu in Android 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2)

The styles go this way:

File *styles.xml*:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>        
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#3892D3</item> 
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme.Text</item>        
</style>    

<!-- 
This style reference did it, you can put a drawable resource or color resource reference there as well. For example: @drawable/menu_dropdown_image or @android:color/white 
-->  
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#3892D3</item>        
</style>
<!---->

<style name="MyActionBarTheme.Text" parent="@android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>    

<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to use [Android Asset studio's ActionBarStyleGenerator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to easily handle colors and not going through all the stuff. If you need more customizing on each Tab then you need to get a reference to actionbar using getActionBar()(or getSupportActionBar() in case of support actionbar) and create custom views Programmatically and add them to your actionbar using addTab(...)