# getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(view) does not fill entire actionbar

Tags: android, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

I'm trying to set the customview of my app and the layout i made does not fill the entire actionbar.
I've tried so many style settings but none has worked for me.

here's my code in activity

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_customized_home, null);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(view);
```

here's the layout placed set as view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/actionbar_color"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Even the background of the menu items like the navdrawer how can I make my customview as background color?

I really appreciate the help

Comment: Try changing the width and height of the RelativeLayout to match_parent instead

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set your main container to this:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/actionbar_color"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The important part is the `android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal` that should solve your problem.

**EDIT:**

if that did not work try doing this:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_customized_home, null);
LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(view, layout);
```

Comment: main container now looks like this:

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/actionbar_color"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/puregold_logo"/>



</RelativeLayout>

Comment: thank you so much!! it extended the view like the whole middle action bar.

Comment: but I still need to set the menu item background to same actionbar color as the custom view. like the drawer button needs to have the same color as the layout background.

Comment: can you please help me with this again?

Comment: Try looking into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2

Comment: for me it worked when i Added
`ActionBar.LayoutParams layout = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); `

use 
`import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;`

Comment: for some reason the edit (dynamic loading) works, but the xml (static) doesn't.

Comment: second soloution worked for me

Answer (score 24):

This is all you need to add in your `onCreate()`

```
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(new CustomView(this));
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); is what did it for me. Thank you.

Comment: This worked. Apparently is required in newer versions. Thank you!

Comment: this does not work for me, it doesn't fill the entire action bar (minus the head/back button on left, and added action buttons on the right). The accepted answer did work

Answer (score 1):

Custom views only occupy the area between the nav/up button and the overflow menu. To change the background and other colors see this - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Comment: hi! thank you for sharing this, now I just need to set the menu item background to the same color as the layout in my custom view.

Comment: I've read that post and tried the styles but it won't change the background of the menu item like the drawertoggle button. I'm using appcompat v7 btw and ActionBarDrawerToggle to help me with the button

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionBar.LayoutParams layout = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewCustom = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_searchview_actionbar, null);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setCustomView(viewCustom, layout);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            Log.i("SEARCH", "ACTIONBAR IS NOT NULL");
        } else
            Log.i("SEARCH", "ACTIONBAR IS NULL :((");
```