# Change style of submenuitem

Tags: android, submenu, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I want to style my submenu (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2)) but it doesn't work.

I try to do this with the  (["Android Action Bar Style Generator"](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=appcompat&theme=light_dark&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=7ba3fd%2C100&secondaryColor=7ba3fd%2C100&tabColor=000%2C100&tertiaryColor=7ba3fd%2C100&accentColor=9c0%2C100&cabBackColor=002E3E%2C100&cabHighlightColor=fb3%2C100)) and this way not applied to me too.

Here is my code...

Java:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.meal, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.itemList);

    for(Item item : o.getItems()){
        menuItem.getSubMenu().add(item.getName());
    }

    return true;
}
```

menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="apppackage" >


    <item android:id="@+id/catList"
        android:title="CatList"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu></menu>

    </item>
</menu>
```

Futhermore I tried this... But it doesn't work.

```
<style name="AppTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/MyWidget.DropDownItem.Spinner</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDropDownNav" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@color/blue</item>
</style>

<style name="MyWidget.DropDownItem.Spinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<style name="AppTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/PopupWrapper</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/MyWidget.DropDownItem.Spinner</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDropDownNav" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@color/blue</item>
</style>

<style name="MyWidget.DropDownItem.Spinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupWrapper" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
</style>
```