# Android OptionsMenu issue, background is always transparent

Tags: android, background-color, transparent, android-optionsmenu

My options menu always shows no background (background is transparent). Does anyone know how to ged rid of this?

My activity where the fail is originated, extends from another custom activity.

I had this project on eclipse and the optionsmenu worked normally, but since I migrated to AndroidStudio, the options menu is always transparent. I've tried to change the menu's xml, and create the menu programatically, but the background still transparent.

Comment: You should copy your gradle file's content, as well as style.xml

Comment: Please post the menu XML. As well, there are still some subtle incompatibilities between Eclipse and Android Studio. For example, I've got some code that will show a notification icon in color if compiled through Eclipse, but that same notification icon will be black and white if imported into Android Studio.

Answer (score 14):

Probably too late, but in case people people end up here via Google (like me).

`Theme.AppCompat` sets `android:panelBackground` to `@android:color/transparent`, which is normally not a problem as if you extend `ActionBarActivity` it handles the options panel creation with a background. However if you are using a standard Activity, with `Theme.AppCompat`, the options menu will be transparent. Fix by either changing the `android:panelBackground` or extending `ActionBarActivity`. Probably extending `ActionBarActivity`.