# Change TextColor / Background of a single ActionBar Menu Item programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is there a way to change the Text color or background color of a single ActionBar menu item by code ?

To be more clear, only one item of the actionBar should have a different color, the rest of them should be the original color.

If so, how exactly can I achieve this.
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but those posts don't answer exactly my question, as I need to change only one item of the actionBar, the rest of them remaining the original color.

Answer (score 0):

add this lines at styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#de5188</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarSubTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarSubTitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10dp</item>
</style>
```

And change your manifasted as

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

I hope this one help to you :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I need to change the color of only one item, the rest of 'em should be the original color.

Comment: No need to be sorry, glad for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Background :

```
 ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"))); //<-- Your Color
```

TextColor :

```
getActionBar()/* or getSupportActionBar() */.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"red\">" + getString(R.string.app_name) + "</font>"));
```

I think you can use both answer @user3515851 and mine.

Comment: If you use this code you have to add this line for all activity.So it will not be better way :)

Comment: Read what he said to you, he only wants to use this of  **only one item**, he can use yours or mine, becase he can define one theme only for one item or just use this on his item..

Comment: The problem is mine.sorry :(

Comment: did my answer helped to you? mark it as a correct if so :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you used a custom Layout for action bar for some cases like this.

```
actionBar.showCustomView(true)// or similar to this.
actionBar.setCustomView(view)// you can inflate the view as you wish
```

so you can customise as it was a normal layout like RelativeLayout.

I hope this helps.