# Android how to change action bar backbutton and overflow button background color on pressed state?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I want to change the background color of the backbutton and overflowmenu button on pressed state.
I am using ActionBarActivity . Appcompact v7 library.
Programmatically is it possible to change background color of the back button and overflowmenubutton ?

Below is my styles:

```
 <resources>

        <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <!-- <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> -->
        </style>

        <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Sri" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
            <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_sri</item>
            <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_sri</item>
            <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_sri</item>
            <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
            <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/action_bar_text_color</item>
            <item name="actionBarDivider">@color/action_bar_text_color</item>
            <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_sri</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Transparent</item>
            <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Transparent</item>

            <!--
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
            <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
            -->

            <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
            <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
            <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView</item>
            <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
            <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView</item>
            <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_sri</item>
            <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_sri</item>
            <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode</item>

            <!--
            <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlowStyle</item>
            <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlowStyle</item>
            -->

            <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav</item>
            <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
            <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
            <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>

            <!-- <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyApp.ActionBar</item> -->
        </style>

        <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_sri</item>
        </style>

        <style name="DropDownListView" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListView.DropDown">
            <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_sri</item>
        </style>

        <style name="PopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
            <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_sri</item>
        </style>

        <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
            <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
            <!-- Support library compatibility -->
            <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
        </style>

        <style name="ActionBar.Transparent" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
            <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_sri</item>
            <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar</item>
            <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
            <!-- Support library compatibility -->
            <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
        </style>

        <style name="ProgressBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
            <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_sri</item>
        </style>

        <style name="OverFlowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
            <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_empty</item>
        </style>

        <style name="TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_text_color</item>
        </style>

        <style name="TabTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_text_color</item>
        </style>

        <style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_sri</item>
            <item name="background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_sri</item>
        </style>

        <style name="DropDownNav" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_sri</item>
            <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_sri</item>
            <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_sri</item>
            <item name="background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_sri</item>
        </style>

        <!--
        <style name="Theme.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

            remove shadow below action bar
            <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
            Support library compatibility
            <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
            <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        </style>
        -->

        <style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">

            <!-- Required for pre-Lollipop. -->
            <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>

            <!-- Required for Lollipop. -->
            <!-- <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item> -->
        </style>

        <style name="ProgressBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />

        <!--
        <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
            <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

            Support library compatibility
            <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
            <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        </style>
        -->


        <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
        <style name="Theme.Sri.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
            <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
            <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView</item>
        </style>

    </resources>
```

Please help me. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

The [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) is very useful, but it generates a lot of files, most of which are irrelevant if you only want to change the background colour please look at this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20077381/611258.

Although i strongly urge you to use the new [toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) or its [support library equivalent.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html)