# how can I change the back ground color of split action bar in android

Tags: android

how can I change the back ground color of split action bar in android?In my application both split actionbar and actionbar is there.

Comment: can you post code how r u used and what you want.

Comment: you want change color with the help of xml??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2/19659779#19659779

Comment: @Allu    <activity
            android:name="com.xxxx.xxx.activities.SessionDetailsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
        </activity> I,ve used the splitactionbar through manifest.

Comment: I want to change the color through code or through manifest.

Comment: are you using AppCompat?

Answer (score 2):

You can change action bar style through style.xml from values.

working with Android API 11+

```
<style name="Theme.Suthar" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Suthar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Suthar" parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

For AppCompat Theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Suthar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Suthar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Suthar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@color/red</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/green</item>
</style>
```