# How to change background of options menu for Android?

Tags: android, android-menu

I've changed background of popup menu, which shows near toolbar. I used this code to change from dark background to light:

`app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"`

Here is the result:

[image]

But when I press menu button on device, it's shows menu with dark background and light text.

[image]

How can I change dark background to light and light text to dark? Or maybe there is exist a anther way. How can I show popupmenu near toolbar instead of dark menu on the bottom of app, after I pressed menu button on device?

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2), I think this is the best solution for your requirement.

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>
<!-- Popup Menu Background Color styles -->
<style name="MyPopupMenu" 
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/Your_color_for_background</item> 
</style>
<!-- Popup Menu Text Color styles -->
<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Your_color_for_text</item>
</style>
```