# How to change text color and background color of action bar items in android

Tags: android

I want to change text color and background color of action bar item which is white here. I searched alot but am not able to change this color.

Please check my code which I am using to customise action bar.

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); 
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor (Hexa color)); 
actionBar . setBackgroundDrawable (colorDrawable);
```

[image: This is the screen in which I want to make changes.]

Comment: final  ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new  ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor (Hexa color));
actionBar . setBackgroundDrawable (colorDrawable);

Comment: I am using above code to customise actionBar. What else I need to do.

Comment: which theme are you using ? **Theme.Holo.Light** or **Holo Dark**

Comment: am using Theme.Holo.Light  Sharp Edge

Comment: then check my answer, and please upvote and accept if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your "res/values/themes.xml" file, do something like this:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
   parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>
<!-- Popup Menu Background Color styles -->
<style name="MyPopupMenu" 
   parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/Your_color_for_background</item> 
</style>
<!-- Popup Menu Text Color styles -->
   <style name="TextAppearance">
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/Your_color_for_text</item>
</style>
```

And then in your manifest

```
<application
   android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" 
... >
```

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2) and some of its answers for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the action bar like below..

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.AppTheme.actionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.AppTheme.actionBar.widget</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/Theme.AppTheme.textView</item>
</style>

<!-- Actionbar things -->

<style name="Theme.AppTheme.actionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.AppTheme.actionBarTitle</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/Theme.AppTheme.actionBarSubtitle</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.AppTheme.actionBarTitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.AppTheme.actionBarSubtitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.AppTheme.actionBar.widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/Theme.AppTheme.actionBar.PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Theme.AppTheme.actionBar.DropDownListView</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.AppTheme.actionBar.PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.AppTheme.actionBar.DropDownListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
</style>

<!-- Standard Widgets -->

<style name="Theme.AppTheme.textView" parent="android:Widget.TextView"></style>
```

Hope this will help you!