# How to change color of menu in actionbar?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I want change background of menu and set it to blue. Now background of my menu is black.How to change this?
Menu xml file :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.nabege.AboutUsActivity" > 

<item
    android:id="@+id/help" 
    android:title="@string/help" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/setting"
    android:title="@string/setting"/>
```

Java codes :

```
  @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.about_us, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: you are using toolbar?? add theme in question

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2

Comment: @programmer138200: change theme dark to light

Comment: Here is tutorial about it: https://www.google.com.np/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiOrOStvefKAhWMBY4KHa72AVg4ChAWCCgwAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.viralandroid.com%2F2016%2F01%2Fhow-to-change-background-and-text-color-of-android-actionbar-option-menu.html&usg=AFQjCNERLPyldALDN8_f54YI_54zgkxOxA&sig2=rkUQ44UbqJzew0ZjY7zdTg&bvm=bv.113370389,d.c2E

Answer (score 0):

Put the following `styles` in your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
        <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color</item>-->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_color</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppThemeActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@color/your_background_color</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps.