# How to change the background color of Action Bar's Option Menu in Android 5.1 & 6.0?

Tags: android

I'd like to change the background color of the option (overflow) menu in Android above 5.0. I have tried all the methods but it is still showing the default color set by the theme. I used the following code & XML configs.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Show up what have you done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy way to change the colors in Actionbar Use [ActionBar Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) and copy paste all file in your res folder and change your theme in Android.manifest file.

Other way is to modify your `styles.xml` like this-

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- This is the styling for action bar -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <!--To change the text styling of options menu items</item>-->
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
    <!--To change the background of options menu-->
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/skyBlue</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@color/red</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle"
    parent="style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
</style>
```

and this is how it looks--MenuItem background color is skyblue and MenuItem text color is pink with textsize as 25sp:--

[image]

This answer is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32324319/5996106).