# Changing menu item's text background in toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, toolbar, menuitem, textcolor

How to change menu item's text background while clicking on it? 
The higlight color on whole item is right, but it seems that text has it's own background color. 
I think that deal is in settin on app:popupTheme, but I don't know what style parameters I should set.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Use this and set the desired color.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

    int positionOfMenuItem = 0; // or whatever...
    MenuItem item = menu.getItem(positionOfMenuItem);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My MenuItem");
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, s.length(), 0);
    item.setTitle(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [How to change the background color of Action Bar's Option Menu in Android 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2/20077381#20077381)

[image: check image]

and for change text color : Setting the **"android:textColor"** will work

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        ...
        <!--This would set the menu item color-->
        <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
        ...
 </style>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The text color is changed, but color of the text background - is still white (it must be gray), when highlight color of whole item is gray.

Comment: plz go through link i have provided in answer@user3352926